# How to get a specific TimeZoneInfo regardless of OS?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, time, timezone

In .NET Core, I'd like to simply convert a UTC DateTime to a one in specific time zone.

Looks like I need to call `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(myUtcDateTime, specificTimeZone)`, but **how to obtain *specificTimeZone***?

Using `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("My timezone name")` seems to be risky as I'd like to use this functionality across different systems which may have their own names for time zones.

Comment: Can I know the reason for the conversion, where do you want to show that converted time? on the UI?

Comment: Sure. My system is using UTC time for convenience, but I'm integrating with a client that expects to receive dates in his local time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding:

> *I'd like to use this functionality across different systems which may have their own names for time zones.*

There are only three possibilities to consider:

- The OS is Windows.  `FindSystemTimeZoneById` and `GetSystemTimeZones` work with Windows time zones.  For example, `"Romance Standard Time"` is the identifier for time in France.
- The OS is non-Windows (OSX, Linux, etc.) and the system has time zone data installed (eg., the `tzdata` package).  `FindSystemTimeZoneById` and `GetSystemTimeZones` work with IANA time zones.  For example, `"Europe/Paris"` is the identifier for time in France.
- The OS is non-Windows and doesn't have time zone data installed.  For example, IoT devices with limited storage, and lightweight container environments.  Notably, Alpine Linux distro doesn't include the `tzdata` package by default.  In this case, `GetSystemTimeZones` returns nothing, and `FindSystemTimeZoneById` always throws a `TimeZoneNotFoundException`.

For the first two concerns, you can leverage my [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter) library.  It will let you use either form of identifier on either platform.

For the last concern, either you need to require that `tzdata` is installed on the OS, or you need to bring your own tzdata, such as libraries like [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org) provide.

Lastly, I'll point out that any time zone data on the OS must be kept updated. Otherwise there's a risk that your code expects a newly-created time zone to exist - but the update containing it hasn't reached the computer yet.  All modern OS's do this automatically unless you specifically configure them not to (ex, Windows Update, etc.)